# line break within cell for huxtable table

Tags: r, r-markdown

I recently started using the [huxtable](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/) R package for tables and I'm really impressed with it. One thing I can't seem to figure out, however, is how to get line breaks *within* a cell. Here's what I've tried

```
library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)
cars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car = rownames(.),
         car = str_replace(car, " ", "\n")) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  select(car, cyl, hp)

cars

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  car                    cyl    hp
  <chr>                <dbl> <dbl>
1 "Mazda\nRX4"          6.00 110  
2 "Mazda\nRX4 Wag"      6.00 110  
3 "Datsun\n710"         4.00  93.0
4 "Hornet\n4 Drive"     6.00 110  
5 "Hornet\nSportabout"  8.00 175 

ht <- as_hux(cars, add_colnames = TRUE)
escape_contents(ht) <- TRUE
ht
```

But this ends up without the line break, as in the screenshot below

[image]

The `escape_contents` part doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm not sure if what I want is possible, but I know it is in other packages (e.g., `DT::datatable`). I'd really like to use huxtable, if possible, however, because I like the design and flexibility of the package.

Any thoughts would be great.

**EDIT:** I should have specified I'm hoping to get this to work for PDF.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Escaping HTML or LaTeX](https://hughjonesd.github.io/huxtable/huxtable.html#escaping-html-or-latex),
You should use `escape_contents(ht) <- FALSE` and use `<br>` tag instead of `\n`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)
cars <- mtcars %>% mutate(car = rownames(.),
                          car = str_replace(car, " ", "<br>")) %>% 
                   slice(1:5) %>% select(car, cyl, hp)

 ht <- as_hux(cars, add_colnames = TRUE)
 escape_contents(ht) <- FALSE
 ht
```

note that the output is a Rmarkdown document and thanks for the package information. it looks good. following is the output of mine

[image]

Comment: Great! However, this looks like it works for HTML but not for PDF. Any thoughts on getting the PDF to work?

Comment: You probably want to use `\newline`, which in R is spelled `"\\newline"`.

Comment: At first, this seemed to work for me, but I had major headaches with LaTeX bugs because I need escaping on. A native solution that doesn't disable escaping is what I would need (but I'm not the OP).

Answer (score 2):

Try this, which minimizes the amount of backslashes:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)

cars <- mtcars %>% mutate(car = rownames(.))
cars$car <- str_replace(cars$car, " ", "\\\\newline ")
cars %>% 
      as_hux(add_colnames = TRUE) %>% 
      set_wrap(TRUE) %>% 
      set_escape_contents(everywhere, "car",  FALSE) %>% 
      quick_pdf()
```

[image]

The `set_wrap()` call is necessary for LaTeX tables to accept newlines, I believe.

If you want to escape different parts of the cells containing newlines, you can do that manually, e.g. with `xtable::sanitize()`.

Comment: This does not work on my machine. The output has no line breaks, not even spaces where the line breaks should be.

Comment: You might want to check your huxtable version. More recent versions simply line wrap with newlines, if `wrap()` is set to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so combining insights from [this LaTeX StackExchange post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell/132661#132661) and [this classic XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1638/) got me this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(huxtable)
cars <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(car = rownames(.),
         car = str_replace(car, "(\\S*)\\s(.*)",
                           "\\\\vtop{\\\\hbox{\\\\strut \\1}\\\\hbox{\\\\strut \\2}}")) %>% 
  slice(1:5) %>% 
  select(car, cyl, hp)

ht <- as_hux(cars, add_colnames = TRUE) %>% 
    set_escape_contents(1:6, 1, FALSE)
theme_article(ht)
```

which gives the following PDF output:

[image]

Of course, you won't need quite as many escapes if you're building your own cells by hand rather than using `str_replace`.  Note that putting `set_escape_contents` to `FALSE` for the cells with line breaks is crucial.