# Place line break within a single cell in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I am working on a Shiny app that collects some user inputs, performs some data processing and finally sends an email to the user with the required output.

While creating the table that I need to send to the user, there is one cell within the table where I need to include line breaks.

You can refer to the image below for the desired output:

[image: r line break desired output]

I have tried using the R code below:

`a <- data.frame("SrNo" = 1, "Description" = "Name: John \n Age: 45")`

I have also tried other variations of line breaks such as \n (with 2 \), \r\n.

However, I only get the following output with a space rather than a line break.

[image: current output line break r]

I have also tried implementing the solution provided at the following link - although without much success.

[line break within cell for huxtable table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398097/line-break-within-cell-for-huxtable-table)

Would be great if you can help me place the line break within the Description column of the data frame.

Comment: Have you checked `\t`?

Comment: @Duck how would you implement that? `a <- data.frame("SrNo" = 1, "Description" = "Name: John \t Age: 45")` doesn't seem to work or if you wrap it in `kable`?

Comment: kable table uses to work with that!

Comment: If you're sending an e-mail to the user, am I correct in assuming that it's a HTML e-mail (rather than plain text), as otherwise it's hard to include tables and other fancy things? Did you already try replacing the \n part with `<br>`, as suggested in the SO thread you linked to? Also, it looks like you pasted a screenshot from within RStudio. Be aware that `<br>` probably won't affect output within RStudio, but can still be correctly rendered in the e-mail. You need to send test e-mails to yourself to see how they work.

Comment: @Duck, can you pls provide the code to implement this in Kable? I am unable to reproduce the same. The \t does not work with a regular data frame.

Comment: @datalowe - Yes, I have tried to implement this when generating the HTML but was unable to, since I am unable to modify the contents of the table. Would really require the line break within the data frame..

Comment: I just tried out the solutions suggested in the thread and they work perfectly with your example if I put the dataframe code (with the `\n`, or replacing that with a `<br>`) in an Rmarkdown doc together with an `as_hux` call and then use knitr to render the document. How are you generating/rendering to HTML? You haven't provided a reproducible example of the problem you are running into.

Comment: But will `\n` or ```<br>``` transfer to a csv output in, say, Excel?